# How to use Azure CosmosDB point-in-time restore with documents having a short TTL

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm experiencing an issue with Azure CosmosDB point-in-time restore feature where documents with a short TTL seem unrecoverable.  Let's say I have documents with a time to live (TTL) of 10 minutes.  If I restore a backup from last week, the TTL is well past expired.  Then those expired documents are deleted very soon after the backup is restored and the data I tried to recover is lost.

I'd expect it to work by Azure setting the timestamp property `_ts` to the time of the restore (that default property is intended to represent the last-updated time of the document).  Having it set to the time of the database restore would then reset the TTL, giving a chance to access the data.  This expected behavior seems confirmed by a [Microsoft Forum post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1295409/how-to-restore-cosmosdb-data)

> When importing a backup of a Cosmos DB database, the _ts (timestamp) fields are automatically updated to the current timestamp during the restore process.

However, my own experience is showing the `_ts` property as not updated by Azure at the time of the restore.  I can't find any more info on that detail in the official documentation.

So what's the correct way to restore data having a short TTL?  Am I missing some necessary restore configuration, is this a bug, or is it just not supported?

---

Additional details:

- I'm using the Cosmos SQL API.
- I'm restoring the entire database account to a new account.

Comment: One of the reasons I don't think this is expected behavior is because it makes the point-in-time restore nearly worthless for Cosmos DBs having data with a TTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. This design decision is documented among the [current limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/continuous-backup-restore-introduction#current-limitations)

> it's possible that the data restored is deleted immediately if you
> configured that way

Hopefully at some point they will improve this - e.g. maybe provide an option to allow the restored backup to be restored in a state with the TTL cleanup disabled.

In the meantime I guess the best that you can do is go and [turn off the TTL feature on the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-time-to-live?tabs=dotnet-sdk-v3#disable-time-to-live-using-an-sdk) immediately the restored backup becomes available and hope that you were fast enough!

The forum thread you link is **not** about the built in back up and restore. They are "storing the backup as JSON in an azure storage account" - which is not how the backup options in the product work. So they must be talking about some export process that they are calling a backup. And where the "restore" is just doing an insert of every document to a new collection